# Git push instead of HEAD:refs/for/master

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a remote git branch that has been newly activated by gerrit review. I tried to push my changes using `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master` but got rejected.

Then i tried to use normal `git push origin` command and i was successfully able to do so. Now the issues is there are some changes in remote that are still under review and my push will break the code flow if they are merged. What should i do. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

- Update local with remote changes `git fetch`
- Pull current branch `git pull origin current-branch-name`
- Push your changes to remote `git push origin current-branch-name`